# Accessing data once Realm Legacy to Mongodb migration is done

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

We have migrated our old data into Atlas db.Android Code refactoring for app is done as well as per the Realm Mongodb Migration guide.
Issue arises when legacy user tries to login first time.
Sequence of steps: Register the legacy user in Auth, login (works till here).

```
public void getUserById(String uid, CompletionUser completionUser) {
    if(realm == null)
        return;
    User userModel = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("_id", uid).findFirst();
    if(userModel != null && userModel.isValid()) {
        completionUser.onSuccess(userModel);
    }
    else {
        completionUser.onFail("User does not found");
    }
}
```

Always returns user not found, even though the data is present in legacy.

Comment: I am not sure the question is clear. If you *register* a user, they would have a different uid. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: In the legacy realm user data is already present.When the legacy database is migrated to Mongodb Realm and if any user is logging in his data is not getting fetched because the above query is returning error

Comment: Realm doesn't have a `User` Realm Object class - that is one you created in your app. Also, there's not code in the question related to 'login first time' so we don't know what's being asked. Are you attempting to load a Realm object from your local database or are you attempting to authenticate to Realm Sync or something else? Please clarify the question

Comment: @Jay i think i figured it out(It was always there and somehow my thought process was different)So before the legacy data was migrated i tested the app for couple of users by registering and logging in it worked. On migration due to large data size the sync was incomplete and when i tried to login and access the user details through the above query it failed most of the times. Have increased the sync time to 120s on login and it works. My thought was if it couldn't fech through the local sync realm should query the atlas and fetch the details.